Custom WordPress REST-API endpoint returns unicode umlauts
I use the WordPress REST-API to upload a csv file and return the content of the file as an HTML table.
As far as I understand the documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#return-value the callback should return the respond, and not echo it. But if I use return, I get all umlauts encoded (/u00fc and not ü). If I echo them, everything is ok.
I guess the problem is that WordPress wraps the returned value by using wp_json_encode() to return json. Of course I can echo the HTML table but I need the data as json, and the HTML is only for developing.
Is there a way to prevent the encoding from umlauts, etc?
If not, how can I undo this at the client by js. I tried to use decodeURIComponent() (once and even twice due to a tip but without hope), I tried unescape().
